# Is it possible for Maven to dynamically set project name based on Git branch name?

Tags: git, maven, maven-2, m2eclipse

If I have a project in a Git repository, like so:

```
  [project.git]/tests/pom.xml
```

And the project has 2 branches, lets say **master** and **develop** .

In that instance I develop code in **develop** and I periodically merge into **master**.

So, I want to be able to import my Maven project into Eclipse (from the same exact codebase) and have Eclipse name the projects distinct from each other.  If I import the project from both branchs, I want Eclipse to show me 2 distinct projects in my Eclipse "project explorer".

So, if I wanted to have the projects be called:

```
developTests
masterTests
```

Is this realistic?  Can this be done?  Can the name property in my pom.xml be dynamic so it can detect the branch name and use it as part of the project name in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

1.) Did you try [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/)? It displays the branch quite well.

2.) These are just thoughts: 
Add gmaven-plugin to your pom and use it to determine the branch name. At the end of the groovy-script use

```
project.properties['project.git.branch']=branchname;
```

to save your branch name as property.

Next, go to File-Import-Existing Maven Projects, in the advanced section as nametemplate enter: [project.git.branch][artifactId]

I found a [groovy get branch example](http://octodecillion.com/blog/current-git-repo-branch-name-using-groovy/), maybe you can fit the parts together?

Disadvantage: I am pretty sure, the eclipse project name will not update dynamically.

[image: Import-Maven-Project]

Comment: I'll try EGit and I will let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through Maven. To do it, you will need to change the `artifactId` (which is what Eclipse will use to figure out what name to set for the project). That may be a bad idea in the fact that if other projects are depending on it, you'll have to change it there as well.

You also cannot use a property for the project's name (`artifactId`), because as far as I recall, you need that set before the interpolation of values.

So -- no, I don't think you can.